# copy text from one slide to other slide with formatting python

Tags: python-pptx

I am trying to copy and paste content from one PPT to other PPT with only certain formatting retained (example: Bold, Italics, Superscript). Below is the code that I have written:

```
def update_text_source_to_template(source_shape, temp_shape):
    for p in source_shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
        formats, newRuns = [], []
        for _, r in enumerate(p.runs):
            # get text
            text = r.text
            newRuns.append(text)
            formats.append({'bold':r.font.bold,
                            'underline':r.font.underline,
                            'italic':r.font.italic,
                            'baseline':r.font._element.get('baseline')})
        print(newRuns)
        text_frame = temp_shape.text_frame
        
        for i in range(len(newRuns)):
            p = text_frame.paragraphs[i]
            run = p.add_run()
            run.text = newRuns[i]
            run.font.bold = formats[i]['bold']
            run.font.italic = formats[i]['italic']
            run.font.underline = formats[i]['underline']
            if (formats[i]['baseline']) != None:
                run.font._element.set('baseline', formats[i]['baseline'])
```

This works without any issue however, I am losing the paragraph structure. For example, below is the text that I copy:

- The twelve principles outlined below are the heart of the book GoodStress:
- The life that can be yours by Wayne FroggattTM (Harper Collins, Auckland, 1997).
- They will help you achieve success at stress management in two ways.
- First, they will help you counter the self-defeating beliefs that create distress.
- Second, they will help you overcome a number of common blocks to using the practical strategies that are a standard part of stress management training.

However, when I paste, it comes as a single paragraph (Example Below)…

```
The twelve principles outlined below are the heart of the book GoodStress: The life that can be yours by Wayne FroggattTM (Harper Collins, Auckland, 1997). They will help you achieve success at stress management in two ways. First, they will help you counter the self-defeating beliefs that create distress. Second, they will help you overcome a number of common blocks to using the practical strategies that are a standard part of stress management training.
```

Is there a way for me to paste it as a list as per the text that we copy???

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you output an extra line or two between each paragraph?

Comment: Thank you for your response Martin. I did try adding a line after the loop of every run. However, the text that I copied might have 1 line or 2 line in between paragraph. Is there a way to read line between paragraphs? If yes, I can store it along with the format and run it in parallel to the text...

Comment: I don't know but does the original have runs that are just a newline or whitespace in general?

Comment: Yes, Martin. The text in the PPT has some blanklines (enters) between each paragraphs. However, in runs it comes as a continuous text.